# modern javascript rest function giving n number of outputs for n number of arguments passed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, parameter-passing

I'm trying to take in multiple episode ids as arguments and display the info of that episode from json data.
I've pushed all the episode info inside the episodeArray
But while displaying it shows the output array two times for two arguments.
How do i display it just one time?

JAVACRIPT CODE

My code is:

```
let episodeData = bigEpisodeData._embedded.episodes

let searchEpisode = (...epiId) => {
  let episodeArray = new Array()
  for (currId of epiId){
    for (currentEpisode of episodeData) {
      let epiInfo = currentEpisode
      if (epiInfo.id === currId) {
        episodeArray.push(epiInfo)
        console.log(episodeArray)
      } 
    }
  }
  }


searchEpisode(3061, 3062)
```

[it is showing the output array two time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1k5l.png)

Comment: Create a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `console.log` outside of the loop

```js
let searchEpisode = (...epiId) => {
  let episodeArray = new Array()
  for (currId of epiId) {
    for (currentEpisode of episodeData) {
      let epiInfo = currentEpisode
      if (epiInfo.id === currId) {
        episodeArray.push(epiInfo)
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(episodeArray)
}
```